# How does a duoplasmatron work?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, particle-accelerators, ions

I'm looking at a diagram of a duoplasmatron ion source and am unclear on the intricacies of the design. The text accompanying the image reads:

> The working principle is based on two-stage discharge. The first
>   discharge (region A of the figure) is produced by electrons generated
>   by a thermo-ionic emission from a filament. Electrons are guided by
>   means of a confining magnetic field into a second chamber (region B)
>   containing the flowing gas. The ionized gas starts a secondary
>   discharge between the intermediate electrode and the anode. Since all
>   the source is kept at 20kV (depending on positive or negative
>   operation) the ions run towards the extraction plate, kept at ground
>   potential.

I understand the thermo-ionic emission from the filament, and I assume the electrons are guided toward region B by the confining effect of the solenoid's magnetic field. However, why is a "secondary discharge" necessary? Wouldn't collisions between the electrons and the flowing gas be enough to ionize the gas? The secondary discharge seems to be an arc current; where exactly is it (it arcs between what two points)? Thanks for any clarification. Here is the link to the paper if needed: https://www.iitk.ac.in/ibc/Ion_Sources.pdf

[image: Diagram]